# Guzzle does not send a post request

Tags: php, guzzle

i'm using PHP with Guzzle.
I have this code:

```
$client = new Client();
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('POST', 'http://localhost/async-post/tester.php',[
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'],
    'form_params' => [
        'action' => 'TestFunction'
    ],
]);


$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});
$promise->wait();
```

For some reason Guzzle Doesn't send the POST Parameters.
Any suggestion?

Thanks :)

Comment: Is it strictly necessary to send the request asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, it must be asynchronous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 things.
The parameters have to go as string (`json_encode`)
And you were also including them as part of the HEADER, not the BODY.

Then i add a function to handle the response as `ResponseInterface`

```
$client = new Client();
$request = new Request('POST', 'https://google.com', ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'], json_encode(['form_params' => ['s' => 'abc',] ]));
/** @var Promise\PromiseInterface $response */
$response = $client->sendAsync($request);
$response->then(
    function (ResponseInterface $res) {
        echo $res->getStatusCode() . "\n";
    },
    function (RequestException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        echo $e->getRequest()->getMethod();
    }
    );
$response->wait();
```

In this test Google responds with a 
Client error: `POST https://google.com` resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed`

But is ok. Google doesn't accepts request like this.

Answer (score 0):

Guzzle isn't truely asynchronous. It's more of multi-threading. That is why you have the `wait()` line to prevent the your current PHP script from closing until all multiple spun threads finish. If you remove the `wait()` line, the PHP process spun by the script ends immediately with all it's threads and your request is never sent.

Ergo, you need Guzzle (and Curl) for multi-processing(concurrent) I/O and not for asynchronous I/O. In your case, you are processing one request and Guzzle promises are simply an overkill.

To send a request with Guzzle, simply do this:

```php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client();
$header = ['Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'];
$body = json_encode(['id' => '2', 'name' => 'dan']);
$request = new Request('POST', 'http://localhost/async-post/tester.php', $header, $body);

$response = $client->send($request);
```

Also, it seems you are using the form `action` attribute rather than the actual form data in `form-params`.

I'm posting this answer because I tried to achieve something really asynchronous with php - Schedule I/O processing as a background task, continue processing script and serve the page; I/O continues in background and completes without disrupting the client. [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues) was the best thing I could find.